# How to tell search engines to only index pages inside my sitemap?

Tags: seo, search-engine, sitemap, google-search-console

Recently my site got hacked and it has been restored. Thousands of spam URLs were indexed by google. I do have a google webmaster account and I can update and submit my sitemap. But how do I tell google to strictly only index the URLs inside my sitemap? I want to prevent any new spam urls created by hackers from being indexed.

Any parameter inside the sitemap.xml that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your sitemap should only include the new URLs and google will **crawl** and **index** only them.

If you have removed the old spammed URLs and they are in 404(not found) status, Google will remove them from the index (albeit quite slowly, it could take even 1-2 months).

If you need to remove those URLs from being **displayed** in the index there's a section about it the webmaster guide: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

Comment: That is not true, thousands of Spam URLs were not in my sitemap, but they were indexed by google.